# Automatic price change on daily basis in magento

Tags: magento-1.4

We have a client site who is having gold jewelery magento shop. In that the jewel prices are daily changing,so he have to update each jewel items price often.

(The logic we have here is 1 gram price today is Rs. 1200 and tomorrow it may became RS. 1220 and client is selling 10 gram item as one jewel and 18 gram item as one jewel and so on, so he have to update the price daily for each jewel item based on its weight).

What we are doing now is having a script that checks and updates price daily based on one input field value from admin config section and cron job.

But what i am looking for is(Well truly its not me, but clients wants better than this solution) a way to automatic price change as like % price based on one gram value(Which can be updated by admin daily in configuration section as like now) daily basis. Is there anyway in magento for this? Please advice me.

Thanks
Ela

Comment: i have also same problem. anybody give an idea plz

Comment: You would need a module for this or some custom work - there's nothing to do this out of the box i'm afraid. I am not even sure there's module out there for this.

Comment: Have you got any solution Ela ...